# функция не работает с jquery-ui-3.2.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть функция , которая добавляет span в input id="to", вот весь код.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            //Присоединяем автозаполнение
            $("#to").autocomplete({

                //Определяем обратный вызов к результатам форматирования
                source: function(req, add){

                    //Передаём запрос на сервер
                    $.getJSON("../../components/airports_search.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {

                        //Создаем массив для объектов ответа
                        var suggestions = [];

                        //Обрабатываем ответ
                        $.each(data, function(i, val){                              
                            suggestions.push(val.index);
                        });

                        //Передаем массив обратному вызову
                        add(suggestions);
                    });
                },

                //Определяем обработчик селектора
                select: function(e, ui) {

                    //Создаем форматированную переменную friend
                    var friend = ui.item.value,
                        span = $("<span>").text(friend),
                        a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({
                            href: "javascript:",
                            title: "Remove " + friend
                        }).text("x").appendTo(span);

                    //Добавляем friend к div friend 
                    span.insertBefore("#to");
                },

                //Определяем обработчик выбора
                change: function() {

                    //Сохраняем поле 'Кому' без изменений и в правильной позиции
                    $("#to").val("").css("top", 2);
                }
            });

            //Добавляем обработчки события click для div friends
            $("#friends").click(function(){

                //Фокусируемся на поле 'Кому'
                $("#to").focus();
            });

            //Добавляем обработчик для события click удаленным ссылкам
            $(".remove", $("#friends")).live("click", function(){

                //Удаляем текущее поле
                $(this).parent().remove();

                //Корректируем положение поля 'Кому'
                if($("#friends span").length === 0) {
                    $("#to").css("top", 0);
                }               
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Не корректно работает функция select

```
//Определяем обработчик селектора
            select: function(e, ui) {

                //Создаем форматированную переменную friend
                var friend = ui.item.value,
                    span = $("<span>").text(friend),
                    a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({
                        href: "javascript:",
                        title: "Remove " + friend
                    }).text("x").appendTo(span);

                //Добавляем friend к div friend 
                span.insertBefore("#to");
            },
```

Сам span появляется в input , но кнопка "x" -> закрыть, не работает.
Не работает она если я подключаю jquery-3.2.1.js и jquery-ui-1.12.1.js.
Если подключить jquery-1.4.2.min.js и jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js все работает. Помогите разобраться что нужно переделать что-бы заработало на последних версиях.

Вот сама форма

```
    <form id="messageForm" action="/search/1" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                  <legend>Поиск</legend>
                        <span>Поиск</span>
                        <div id="searchform">
                           <label id="toLabel">Индекс Аэропорта:</label>
                           <div id="friends" class="ui-helper-clearfix" >
                           <input id="to" type="text">
                        </div>
                        ........                           

          <button type="submit" id="send">Отправить</button>

              </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: а ошибку какую в консоли пишет?

Comment: @humster_spb jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).live is not a function, этот метод устарел, как его заменить корректно???

Comment: ну, гуглите, как заменить live: https://www.meweb.ru/articles.php?article_id=59

Comment: @humster_spb я не силён в js  , не пойму как заменить на on в моём случае

Comment: в смысле "не пойму"? просто меняете live на on и тестируете. если не работает, смотрите, какую ошибку на этот раз пишет

Comment: @humster_spb Я сделал вот так $(".remove", $("#friends")).on("click", function(){ ... Теперь нет ошибки но не работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72036/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-humster-spb).

Comment: я почему-то не могу в чат писать, не понимаю, что за глюк. добавьте в код ваш html - может быть, какая-то проблема с селекторами...

Comment: @humster_spb Добавил

Comment: Ну, так, вроде, всё ок (только у Вас div#friends не закрыт). Попробуйте при объявлении переменных $("<span>") заменить на $("span") и $("<a>") - на $("a")

Comment: @humster_spb , попробывал, теперь даже крестик "x" не появляется

Comment: а Вы можете здесь привести воспроизводимый пример? чтобы было видно, что и как работает (а не просто код). Или дать ссылку?

Comment: @humster_spb там нужен mysql, данные беруться из БД